# Android Studio: Are Library Project dependencies picked from project.properties?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I have imported my project from ADT and after going to "Module Settings" and editing dependencies things are working fine.
My "build.gradle" has dependencies block empty, So I am wondering from where is Ansdroid-Studio picking libraries dependencies ? As I migrated from eclipse so I have project.properties file in module directory. Does Android-studio pick these things from "project.properties" file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android Studio's default project support is done through Gradle, unless you have an Android project coming from IntelliJ which you can open with Studio as well.

If you use Gradle, project.properties is completely ignored. You should not use the Module Settings to add dependencies now as it only changes the IDE but not the Gradle based build system (we'll fix this in later versions).

If you have missing dependencies in your build.gradle, it may be due to a bug in the export from ADT. We have fixes for this coming soon.

Comment: Thanks. So Where are any changes we make from "Module Settings" stored ? In metadata ?

Comment: They are stored in IntelliJ's own project data. So editing feature are impacted by this (like code completion, refactoring, etc...) However building is done externally through Gradle which uses it's own project definition in build.gradle.

Comment: If project building is independent of IDE ( Thats what i learned from IO session video ) then how come my projects are building fine in IDE even with empty 'dependencies' block in build.gradle ? Or There are still some differences in building from IDE and command-line directly ?

Comment: Are you really "building" from the IDE, or is it just that code completion works in the IDE? If you setup dependencies in the IDE, code completion will work, but building will not.

Comment: I did setup dependencies in IDE and also building from IDE only. I didn't check code-completion but build completes fine.

Comment: It just means you are not build with Gradle.

Comment: Yes Xav, you are right. I was doing 'make compile'. I think its 'make build' which uses gradle. I am new to IntelliJ so not so much familiar with it. Please try to fix export app feature in ADT bundle because that is causing a lot of trouble to a lot of people. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, since a new project on Android Studio does not generate a `project.properties` file.

Presumably in Android Studio that is not where dependencies are coming from, but I can't be too sure.