# ActionBar Sherlock with Android Studio 0.2.2

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I am developing a demo app using ActionBar Sherlock and Android Studio.
Android Studio Version is 0.2.2, gradle version is 1.6 and plugin version is 0.5.1 and i am following these tutorials :-

[www.grokkingandroid.com](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-actionbarsherlock-to-your-project/) 
[showlabor.blogspot.ca](http://showlabor.blogspot.ca/2013/05/actionbarsherlock-in-android-studio-01.html)

i am getting following error :-

```
 Gradle: Execution failed for task ':libraries:ActionBarSherlock:actionbarsherlock:compileReleaseAidl'.tried to access class com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DependencyBasedCompileTask$DepFileProcessor from class com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DependencyBasedCompileTask
```

actionbarsherlock build.gradle file goes like this :-

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library' 

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 17
  buildToolsVersion '17.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }

 }
```

and my project build file goes like this :-

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
}
dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:ActionBarSherlock:actionbarsherlock')
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

any leads on this is highly appreciated

Thanks :)

Comment: Where in your project in the IDE did you add ActionBarSherlock - did you import it as a library project, or used  jar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
}
```

Comment: for which gradle file can u please be more specific !!

Comment: for your project - you do not need to touch ABS that way any more - all fetched from maven central - that is now possible as ABS is now available as AAR through maven central - no more workarounds needed

Comment: same as posted in question

Comment: you need to remove this line compile project(':libraries:ActionBarSherlock:actionbarsherlock')

Comment: Gradle: Execution failed for task ':SherlockTest:processDebugManifest'.
 Manifest merging failed. See console for more info.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34478/discussion-between-r4jiv007-and-ligi)

Comment: @ligi, found a solution for this error? I am still getting this same error.

Comment: You will get errors if support-v7 is also in your dependencies; consider switching from ActionBarSherlock to ActionBarCompat from the support v7 library if you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error until I used the same gradle file as the one from the sample for ABS and gradle here, that's a working sample project: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock-Gradle-Sample

Comment: That requires that you put a build folder and insert an exploded-bundles directory into it called: ComActionbarsherlockActionbarsherlock440.aar

It's a very convoluted setup.