# Android Studio - Gradle Manifest Merging Failed

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-manifest, android-studio, build.gradle

I am building a demo app using actionbar sherlock in android studio and i was facing problem , mentioned in following link :-
[Previous Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945111/actionbar-sherlock-with-android-studio-0-2-2)

now after following the replies posted on above link i did some changes and now i am facing this

```
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':SherlockTest:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merging failed. See console for more info.
```

my application manifest file is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sherlocktest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sherlocktest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and  actionbar sherlock manifest file is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:versionCode="440"
          android:versionName="4.4.0"
          package="com.actionbarsherlock">

  <uses-sdk
          android:minSdkVersion="10"
          android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>

  <application/>

</manifest>
```

i am not able to figure out what is the problem here, please help

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Make sure that in all your build.gradle scripts the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion correspond to those you have in your manifests:

```
android {
    defaultConfig { 
       minSdkVersion 10
       targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

This worked for me, I hope it does the trick for you, cheers.

Comment: This didn't help for me.

Comment: The versions should be written as integers and not strings. Added an edit.

Answer (score 4):

For what I can see, if you have a multi-module project with Android Studio and gradle, the IDE try to **merge manifest files** from every module into a Main manifest.

If you have a module A and a module B, and in the A manifest you declare some activity from B module, gradle will enconter a issue when merging.

Try **removing cross-module reference** in manifest files.

Comment: can u help me i had posed a question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266042/how-to-fix-dexdebugtest-in-android-stuio

Answer (score 3):

That worked for me when adding the Google Play Services

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That works for me.
My library project AndroidManifest.xml miss a application element
add one will fix it.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>
```

I use *gradle clean projectName **--info*** get the error information, and solve it.

Comment: @Taranmeet at your root project folder, run gradle clean projectName --info