# "The command line is too long" error in dexDebugTest build task

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio

I followed [this link](http://rexstjohn.com/unit-testing-with-android-studio/) to set up test cases in Android Studio:

But if I try to run some tests in my project I get the following error:

```
**Execution failed for task ':common_lib_app:dexDebugTest'.**
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android_studio\sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\dx.bat --dex --num-threads=4 --output D:\Android\android_studio\

update error:

The command line is too long.

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':commom_lib_app:dexDebugTest'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android_studio\sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\dx.bat --dex --num-threads=4 --output D:\Android\android_studio\app\Delivery\25-11-14\app\commom_lib_app\build\intermediates\dex\test\debug D:\Android\android_studio\app\Delivery\25-11-14\app\commom_lib_app\build\intermediates\classes\test\debug D:\Android\android_studio\app\Delivery\25-11-14\app\commom_lib_app\build\intermediates\dependency-cache\test\debug D:\Android\android_studio\app\Delivery\25-11-14\app\commom_lib_app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\test\debug\android-viewbadger-9d48585bb36d47b79a1e72c63063924a4680e127.jar D:\Android\android_studio\app\Delivery\25-11-14\app\commom_lib_app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\test\debug\annotations-12.0-74efc7d81ba4e593d47bf812f81a6e79e66e3a94.jar D:\Android\android_studio\app\Delivery\25-11-14\app\commom_lib_app\intermediates\pre-dexed\test\debug\apktool-lib-1.4.4-3-e106601b170eeb66eba64dc7a8f7b456d516b9f3.jar D:\Android\android_studio\app\Delivery\25-11-14\app\commom_lib_app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\test\debug\bolts-
```

I have multiple projects with a common library class (i.e ==common_lib_app).

Here is my **build.gradle**:

```
 androidTestCompile('junit:junit:4.11') {
  exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-library'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.0'
    compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-2'
    compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-2'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.5.4'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:endless:1.2.3'
    compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:library:2.6.0'
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have more output from the exception? Specifically what fails?

Comment: yes let me edit my issues in above

Comment: i had updated some more error can u plz see it

Comment: actually here i am using robotium because of multiple project with the common library class

Comment: tried by changing the min and max target version but no change

Comment: searched a lot and tried to fix with some found solution but no changes

Comment: do u need some more error or what is it ok

Comment: is there any option to go on

Answer (score 1):

This is bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75936 (Support new dx option: --input-list=) which has been fixed in later versions of Android Studio. I believe you're running an older version; a modern version wouldn't allow you to use Build Tools 19.1.0. Try updating Android Studio, following its instructions to update your build scripts to use the latest version of the Android Gradle plugin, and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: @Manoj have you tried updating the build tools, grade plugin and android studio ?

Comment: yes it shows me message that you are using latest beta version but it is not latest version plz have a look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288367/how-to-update-android-studio-beta-channel

Comment: now i am using Android studio 1.0 RC 4 but shows me the error as Gradle DSL method not found:'useOldManifestMerger()' i had removed it and run now it shows as Gradle DSL method not found:'apply()' how to fix this issue

Comment: @Scott Barta now i am using Android studio 1.0 RC 4 but shows me the error as Gradle DSL method not found:'useOldManifestMerger()' i had removed it and run now it shows as Gradle DSL method not found:'apply()' how to fix this issue

Comment: @Ahmad Ali Nasir Ali Nasir now i am using Android studio 1.0 RC 4 but shows me the error as Gradle DSL method not found:'useOldManifestMerger()' i had removed it and run now it shows as Gradle DSL method not found:'apply()' how to fix this issue

Comment: @Manoj Please share your latest Gradle build script

Comment: @Ahmad Ali Nasir !!! JUnit version 3.8 or later expected:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
 at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.<init>(BaseTestRunner.java:5)
 at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:54)
 at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:48)
 at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:41)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.junitVersionChecks(JUnitStarter.java:190)

Comment: @Ahmad Ali Nasir i have several test case from baseActivity when i run my test case each individually i run's but if run from baseActivity by picking the option all it cases the error as JUnit version 3.8 or later expected: so updated with latest version but it remains the same is there any other go for solution

Comment: @Manoj sorry for the late reply, but I have to look into it. If its possible for you to share your project, it may speed up things. Let me know if its possible, you can email me as well.

Comment: @Ahmad Ali Nasir thanks a lot for your time bro i had fixed it.