# How to update Android Studio Beta Channel

Tags: android, plugins, android-studio, ide, auto-update

I am using Android Studio when ever i try to update it shows me the below

[image]

How can i update it and also tried by using the option Help->checkForUdates but it shows the same.

Comment: click Updates in your dialog and change to beta chanel

Answer (score 18):

1. In Android Studio go to "File > Settings > Updates"
2. change the "Stable channel" option to "canary channel".
3. After that go to "Help > Check for update ...".
4. You should get a pop-up with the option to "update and restart"

Here is the [Official documentation](http://tools.android.com/preview-channel)

Regards Jose

Comment: Its under File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Updates now

Answer (score -1):

According to [the release notes](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio0812released):

> **Note:** There are no incremental patches to update to 0.8.12; you will need to download it separately

Which means that if you want to update from a version <0.8.12 to the latest beta, which is 0.8.14, then you will need to [redownload Android Studio](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/0-8-14).

Comment: But in my other system it automatically asked for update i updated it to 0.8.14.

Comment: You could try looking in `%HOMEPATH%\.AndroidStudioPreview\config\options\other.xml` for the `myIgnoredBuildNumbers` block.