# How do I update android studio 2.3.2 to 3.0 on ubuntu?

Tags: android, android-studio

Actually I want to try the kotlin language which requires android studio 3.0, but I have 2.3.2. So how do I update the thing on Ubuntu?

Comment: Pretty sure that's all included in the documentation

Comment: What happened when you typed "Android Studio 3" into your favourite search engine?

Comment: just took 1min to search https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update Android Studio Beta Channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288367/how-to-update-android-studio-beta-channel)

Comment: Thanks for not helping!

Comment: @Redman: is there any mention of *updating* on that page? I could not find it.

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/install-preview.html)  and download latest android studio 3.0 canary 7 for linux from my above link or [this](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/3.0.0.6/android-studio-ide-171.4182969-linux.zip)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I found out that many versions of Android Studio can be installed side by side which is better for me since I wan to have the old one also:

https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/install-preview.html

Comment: side-by-side is the best option for Studio 3.0. The Android Studio team is not offering update patches from Studio 2.3 (stable) --> Studio 3.0 (canary).

Answer (score 1):

You can also upgrade android studio from older version to new version.
Go to `Help -> Check` for Updates
Then the update window will appear, Select `Update and Restart` button or `Update Now` if you are updating Plugins.

Usually, there is an issue with the upgradation i.e. When we click "update and restart" it says "Downloading patches" and it closes after or before downloading the entire patches. It does not start again and if we try to open it, the version is still the older one. I found that after the patch is downloaded Android Studio tries to update itself but as it is run without sudo rights it fallbacks to simply run the old version of Android Studio without updating it.

So to fix it go to the folder where Android studio was installed, usually, it is `/usr/local/android-studio/bin` and go to sudo mode using `sudo -i` and then run `./studio.sh`or run `sudo ./studio.sh` (but it didn't work for me)  and try to download the patches again probably now it should get updated.

This will preserve the confriguration of your older version of Android Studio.

Comment: I tried this method earlier and it worked for me

Answer (score -3):

You have to install Android Studio 2.3 first [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html).

Next, you install it following the introduction.

Download Android Studio 3.0 [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html). Remember to choose Linux version.

Just open it in: /bin/androidstudio

[image]

Comment: Why do you first need a lower version?

Comment: Because the Android Studio 3.0 do not include Android SDK.

Comment: Neither does 2.3... You download that all separately as part of the installation or using the SDK Manager after starting the first time

Comment: Because this's a very dummy topic therefore I wrote a most easy way. With my solution, you only click on next next next button without any question else.

Comment: But downloading two IDEs wasn't the question. It was how to update the current one